# Strange Crashes in Batch File

Tags: batch-file

I am starting what will most likely be the most tedious part of a batch game I'm making: the maps. My location checking system has some issues, however.

```
:location_check_k
if %k_loc%==1 goto k_1
if %k_loc%==2 goto k_2
if %k_loc%==3 goto k_3
if %k_loc%==4 goto k_4
if %k_loc%==5 goto k_5
if %k_loc%==6 goto k_6
if %k_loc%==7 goto k_7
if %k_loc%==8 goto k_8
if %k_loc%==9 goto k_9
if %k_loc%==10 goto k_10
if %k_loc%==11 goto k_11
if %k_loc%==12 goto k_12
if %k_loc%==13 goto k_13
if %k_loc%==14 goto k_14
if %k_loc%==15 goto k_15
if %k_loc%==16 goto k_16
if %k_loc%==17 goto k_17
if %k_loc%==18 goto k_18
if %k_loc%=="" goto error
if %k_loc% GTR 18 goto error

:k_1
::Gate
set "dc="
type data\mapdata\maps\kinallen\maps\kinallen_ex_s
set\p dc=
if %dc%=up goto k_4
goto k_1
```

That's all I've got for the system so far, but it crashes every time. I've tried cutting out parts of the code to find where the error originates, but nothing works. None of the variables are false. I've tried putting in `echo %k_loc%` before these lines. It returns "1," as it should. The files mentioned in the `type` commands exist, too. Deleting certain chunks does nothing, either. Getting rid of the `:location_check_k` section still produces a crash. Replacing everything in the `:k_1` section with just `echo good` and `pause` still produces a crash.

Things to note:

-`k_(number)` is what I'm using as the map location value. Each different number will type the same map, with you in a different location.

-The variable `dc` is the abbreviation I'm using for "direction command."

-This is launched through a `call` command. I'm keeping the code more organized this way.

-The other locations (`k_2`...`k_18`) have not been written out yet.

Unsure if any of those would affect anything, but I'm listing them anyway. Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You may be able to change all those lines in `:location_check_k` for `GoTo k_%k_loc% 2>Nul||GoTo error`. Oh and `set\p` should be `Set/P`

Comment: The backslash was the issue. Guess I was too used to typing the filepaths, huh :P

Comment: either way, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are more errors in the code:

```
if %k_loc%=="" goto error
```

will never execute the goto, either

```
if "%k_loc%"=="" goto error
```

or better

```
if not defined k_loc goto error
```

The set /p was aleady mentioned, but change

```
if %dc%=up goto k_4
```

to

```
if /i "%dc%"=="up"
```

If it's your plan to do typing exercises you may do as above, but as @Compo suggested there are more efficient methods for the 18 goto commands

```
GoTo k_%k_loc% 2>Nul||GoTo error
```

or

```
For /l %%c in (1 1 18) Do If "%k_loc%"=="%%a" Goto k_%%a
```